# How to apply check until required amount is paid for?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a back deposit system that requires user to deposit amount of 65000, account holder should be keep deposing money until full amount of 65000 is paid. I tried to do this with do while loop but it is just working as variable and not checking how much money is paid. Here is sample of code:

```
int user_fee;
int deposited=65000;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("please enter fee");
    user_fee = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    obj.Fee = user_fee;
} while (user_fee<= deposited);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [do while loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539009/do-while-loop-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @XavierBalloy The issue is far more trivial than the suggested duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're replacing user_fee with the input fee infinitely.

Change

```
user_fee = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

to

```
user_fee += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

This way, you'll keep adding the new fee into `user_fee`.

EDIT:

Full solution, as it seems I wasn't clear:

```
int user_fee;
int deposited=65000;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("please enter fee");
    user_fee += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    obj.Fee = user_fee;
} while (user_fee<= deposited);
```

Let me know if this works for you. Also, why's the reason for using `obj.Fee = user_fee`?

Comment: sorry for my idiotic question...bro i  am beginner programmer and thanks for your reply. i tried to do this but it throwing error                                                                                                                       do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter fee");
                user_fee = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                obj.Fee = user_fee;
                user_fee +=; // error (invalid expression)
            } while (user_fee<= deposited);

Comment: @OmarAeo That's because you need to use `int user_fee = 0;`

Comment: I see where the error is Omar. `user_fee +=;` is not a valid expression. :-) Give me a minute and I'll post the entire loop for you. :-)

Comment: o
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter fee");
                user_fee = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                obj.Fee = user_fee;
                user_fee = user_fee+user_fee;
            } while (user_fee< deposited);

Comment: still not wotking

Comment: Please update your latest, non-working, version of the loop in the answer with formatting. Also include the error log. :-)

Comment: i did please refresh this page

Comment: Sipty you have done some magic :) its working now.. but may i know why `user_fee = user_fee+user_fee;` is not same as `user_fee += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`  Isnt both statment same?

Comment: i am using `obj.Fee` because i am using class object

Comment: Hello Omar, user_fee + user_fee is equivalent to user_fee*2 :-) The += adds the new value to the existing one, so in our case it's equivalent to user_fee = user_fee + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); Hope this helps and goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Sipty you have done some magic :) its working now.. but may i know why 
`user_fee = user_fee+user_fee;` is not same as `user_fee += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`; Isnt both statment same? – `user_fee = user_fee+user_fee;` is also adding user_fee into itself after each loop iteration btw thanx..
btw i am using `obj.Fee` because i am using class object